# Why cat $(find /usr/portage -name *.ebuild) | grep RESTRICT - works? And find | grep - not?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

Why I can't grep find? Only helps grepping cat of find. 
As I see program grep could see some context in which every command runs. But it's counterintuitive for a newbie like me. When given with argument grep can search files , but when it's with pipe ( | ) - it couldn't.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9125/how-do-i-find-text-within-a-file-and-have-it-search-multiple-subfolders solution to same problem..

Comment: Both work, one looks for dashes the other for RESTRICT, what makes you conclude it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

The `find` command generates a list of pathnames that match the search criteria, in this case, a name with an `.ebuild` extension.  (But minor quibble:  You need quotes around the wildcard so the shell will pass it to find without trying to expand it first.)  If you pipe that into `grep`, all you're doing is filtering that list of names, not the contents of those files.

By contrast, the `cat $(find ...)` construct uses command substitution (that's the `$(...)` part) to paste the output of find (the list of pathnames it generates) back onto the command line as arguments to `cat`, causing `cat` to write the contents of those files to stdout and into `grep`.

The simpler way to do what you want would be to use command substitution to pass the names to `grep` directly:

```
grep RESTRICT $(find /usr/portage -name "e.build")
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking. I might add a `-maxdepth` argument in there as well depending on the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

To express Nicole Hamilton's command in a more concise form you can use the -exec flag to the find command.

```
find /usr/portage -name '*.ebuild' -exec grep RESTRICT {} \;
```

This passes the names of the matched files to grep with the curly brackets being replaced by the filename. The '\;' is an escaped ';' this is used to signify the end of the command.

## Performance @garyjohn

This is a comparison of different timings for running the find command. All these tests where performed against a recent snapshot of portage (http://distfiles.gentoo.org/snapshots/portage-latest.tar.bz2). I ran 'find .' and 'grep -Rni . .' before timeing these tests so I'm hoping that disk and ram caching should be simular across all tests.

Here is the timing for the two commands:

```
% time grep RESTRICT $(find . -name "*.ebuild") > /dev/null
grep --color RESTRICT $(find . -name "*.ebuild") > /dev/null  0.05s user 0.13s system 95% cpu 0.192 total

% time find . -name "*.ebuild" -exec grep RESTRICT {} \; > /dev/null
find . -name "*.ebuild" -exec grep RESTRICT {} \; > /dev/null  0.68s user 2.63s system 14% cpu 22.523 total
```

As your can see the cat method is much quicker completing in about 5% of the time of my example.

However if the find command returns too many files we run into a limit of the shell with the lenght of a single command. This will cause the command to fail.

```
% time grep RESTRICT $(find . -name "*") > /dev/null
zsh: argument list too long: grep
grep --color RESTRICT $(find . -name "*") > /dev/null  0.34s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 0.374 tota
```

To see this limit on your system use.

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

Here is find running with the same glob. Notice that it takes a very long time to complete but it does exit succesfully.

```
% time find . -name "*" -exec grep RESTRICT {} \; > /dev/null    
find . -name "*" -exec grep RESTRICT {} \; > /dev/null  2.52s user 11.00s system 12% cpu 1:47.67 total
```

The optimal way to safley run this command is to use xargs.

```
% time find . -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep RESTRICT > /dev/null 
find . -name "*" -print0  0.16s user 0.29s system 51% cpu 0.886 total
xargs -0 grep RESTRICT > /dev/null  0.33s user 0.59s system 100% cpu 0.915 total
```

Using xargs it is possible to grep through the entire portage tree (~159995 files, 724M) in just under 2 seconds.

Comment: This is slower--possibly much slower--than Nicole's command because it executes grep once for every file searched.

Comment: Thanks for the timing comparison.  Good point about using `xargs` if the arg list is too long.  In this case that appears not to be a problem given that the OP states that command substitution onto `cat` worked.